# How to assign a priority to a method in Ray?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, ray

I am using Ray to train a distributed RL algorithm. However, the algorithm slows down massively (in terms of how many gradient steps / wall time it does) when using the distributed settings vs. non-distributed. My current theory is that due to the distributed actors collecting data and all wanting to access the shared memory, the algorithm (which samples from this memory) has to wait in a queue to access it. I want to assign a higher priority to one of the memory methods than the others so that it will get executed as soon as possible when called.

Below is an example of what the replay memory looks like (I've changed what the methods do for the purpose of the example):

```
import ray
from collections import deque
import time


@ray.remote
class ReplayBuffer:
    def __init__(self, capacity, batch_size=128):
        self.buffer = deque(maxlen=capacity)
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def sleep(self):
        time.sleep(10)

    def print_(self):
        print('here')

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.buffer)


buffer = ReplayBuffer.remote(1)

[buffer.sleep.remote() for i in range(5)]
buffer.print_.remote()
```

How can I assign a higher priority to the `print_` method, over the `sleep` method? Ideally, how it would run is that even though there would be 4 `sleep` calls waiting, once the `print_` method is called it gets pushed ahead of the `sleep` in the queue, so instead of waiting 50 seconds to print 'here' it would be done after 10 seconds. Is this possible in Ray? I can't find anything useful in their documentation, but I am quite new to using Ray so I may be looking in the wrong area.

Answer (score 0):

ray has no priority config

you can see this document

https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/cluster/faq.html#do-ray-clusters-support-multi-tenancy

I think the priority config is a very good idea for ray, with priority ray will extend many usage